# union vs void*, which is better for what?

Tags: c, void, unions

When I first learned about union wasn't obvious, but after I learned C++ runtime [polymorphism](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polimorfizm_(informatyka)), I had a thought. Why do I use `union` instead of `void*`? I created a short code example for both.

Here is the `union` example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int N = 10;

union int_double_t
{
    int i;
    double d;
};

enum int_double_label
{
    INT, DOUBLE
};

struct labeled_int_double_t
{
    enum int_double_label label;
    union int_double_t value;
};

int main()
{
    struct labeled_int_double_t u[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        if (rand() % 2)
        {   
            u[i].label = INT;
            u[i].value.i = i;
            printf("array[%i]:     %s\t%i\n", i, u[i].label ? "double" : "int", u[i].value.i);
        }
        else
        {
            u[i].label = DOUBLE;
            u[i].value.d = i + .1;
            printf("array[%i]:     %s\t%f\n", i, u[i].label ? "double" : "int", u[i].value.d);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `void*` example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int N = 10;

enum int_double_label
{
    INT, DOUBLE
};

struct labeled_int_double_t
{
    enum int_double_label label;
    void* value;
};

int main()
{
    struct labeled_int_double_t u[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        if (rand() % 2)
        {   
            u[i].label = INT;
            u[i].value = malloc(sizeof(int));
            *(int*)u[i].value = i;
            printf("array[%i]:     %s\t%i\n", i, u[i].label ? "double" : "int", *(int*)u[i].value);
            free(u[i].value);
        }
        else
        {
            u[i].label = DOUBLE;
            u[i].value = malloc(sizeof(double));
            *(double*)u[i].value = i + .1;
            printf("array[%i]:     %s\t%f\n", i, u[i].label ? "double" : "int", *(double*)u[i].value);
            free(u[i].value);
        }
    }
}
```

Both compiled with: `gcc -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99`, both run as expected.

Here is the output:

```
array[0]:     int       0
array[1]:     int       1
array[2]:     double    2.100000
array[3]:     double    3.100000
array[4]:     int       4
array[5]:     double    5.100000
array[6]:     double    6.100000
array[7]:     double    7.100000
array[8]:     double    8.100000
array[9]:     double    9.100000
```

I kind of see the difference.  With `union`, I'm able to use only stack memory, but is there any other fundamental differences?

Comment: For starters your `void*` example uses `malloc` which means it has extra overhead from dynamic memory allocation. Also a `union` only allows a specific set of types, while a `void*` allows any kind of pointer (to any type)

Comment: Also a `union` has a guaranteed memory layout, with a `void*` you have no information about how large the pointed to memory is (unless you save that information somewhere).

Comment: Duplicate [union versus void pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821486/union-versus-void-pointer?rq=3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you know what you are doing, and still know what you did, there is not a lot of difference.
But otherwise (the code is by a colleague, or by you before the three week vacation on a beach you just had) you will be happy for any enforced clarity and any small thing where the compiler can detect a mistake for you.
This might seem irrelevant for the single programmer who is constantly working on the code in question, but for old, large or multi-location projects I feel like "`*void` is unlucky." so much so that I needed some time to realise that it is not a general rule before writing this. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Which is better depends on higher level context use.  Something not shown.

In select cases, each approach is superior.

---

Some [pros and cons](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pros_and_cons#Noun):

`union`

Pro: Simple.
Pro: No allocation error.
Pro: Only simple copy needed.
Pro: Size information part of `union`.
---: All objects the same size.
Con: Wasteful when possible object types differ *greatly* in size.

`malloc`

Pro: each right-object sized.
Con: each object has pointer overhead.
Con: allocation may fail.
Con: Copies only pointer.  Need more code to copy referenced object.
Con: Small object allocations fracture memory.
Con: Companion `free()` needed.

--

For just `int i, double d`, I would more likely use the `union` approach.

Aside: what is the opposite of progress?

> Congress

Comment: This seems biased against `void*`

Comment: @MehdiCharife, Yes `union` is better that `void *` in most cases.

Comment: I'm not entirely decided, but it seems to me that using a `union` is nightmare to maintain. Each use of the `union` requires the use of a `switch` statement, and in case you needed to support an additional type, you'd have to go all through these statements and add an additional case.

Comment: @MehdiCharife Perhaps post your 2 implementations ( as a questions) via `void *` and `union` and ask how to improve.

Comment: I don't think that any implementations will greatly diverge from the ones described by the OP. Other than that, a question like the one you're suggesting seems off-topic on SO. It could be better suited for CodeReview, but it probably would end up as a duplicate there as it's likely someone have already posted a very similar implementation.

Comment: True that they would not diverge much, yet I expect your question would be acceptable on either site and you would benefit.  Good luck.