# Union vs void pointer performance

Tags: c, unions, void-pointers

TL;DR is union better in terms of performance than void pointer

When I was searching for Union vs void pointer performance I gone thorough this question [Union versus void pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821486/union-versus-void-pointer).
Many suggested to use union but none of it is because of performance. My question is does void pointer take more time than union since we need to type cast it again and again.

I wrote the below code to test the performance and found that union is much better.

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct union_test union_test;
typedef struct void_test void_test;
typedef void (*PrintUnionFunction)(union_test *);
typedef void (*PrintVoidFunction)(void_test *);

typedef enum ELEM_TYPE
{
    INT_TYPE,
    STRING_TYPE,
    FLOAT_TYPE
} ELEM_TYPE;

struct union_test
{
    ELEM_TYPE elemType;
    union {
        int **intElems;
        float **floatElems;
        char **stringElems;
    };
    size_t elemCount;
    PrintUnionFunction printFunction;
};

struct void_test
{
    ELEM_TYPE elemType;
    void **elems;
    size_t elemCount;
    PrintVoidFunction printFunction;
};

void printUnionInt(union_test *fpTest)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < fpTest->elemCount; i++)
    {
        int *temp = fpTest->intElems[i];
        (*temp)++;
        // printf("%d ", *fpTest->intElems[i]);
    }
}

void printVoidPointerInt(void_test *fpTest)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < fpTest->elemCount; i++)
    {
        int *temp = ((int *)fpTest->elems[i]);
        (*temp)++;
        // printf("%d ", *fpTest->intElems[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    clock_t start_time_union, end_time_union;
    clock_t start_time_void, end_time_void;
    size_t elemCount = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;

    union_test *fp = (union_test *)malloc(sizeof(union_test));
    fp->elemCount = elemCount;
    fp->elemType = INT_TYPE;
    fp->printFunction = printUnionInt;
    fp->intElems = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * fp->elemCount);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < fp->elemCount; i++)
    {
        fp->intElems[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
        memcpy(fp->intElems[i], &i, sizeof(int));
    }

    void_test *void_fp = (void_test *)malloc(sizeof(union_test));
    void_fp->elemCount = elemCount;
    void_fp->elemType = INT_TYPE;
    void_fp->printFunction = printVoidPointerInt;
    void_fp->elems = (void **)malloc(sizeof(void *) * void_fp->elemCount);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < void_fp->elemCount; i++)
    {
        void_fp->elems[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
        memcpy(void_fp->elems[i], &i, sizeof(int));
    }

    start_time_union = clock();
    fp->printFunction(fp);
    end_time_union = clock();

    start_time_void = clock();
    void_fp->printFunction(void_fp);
    end_time_void = clock();

    printf("\n\nunion execution time: %f seconds\n", (double)(end_time_union - start_time_union) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printf("void pointer execution time: %f seconds\n", (double)(end_time_void - start_time_void) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    return 0;
}
```

I got the below results.

```
union execution time: 8.237730 seconds
void pointer execution time: 8.647505 seconds
```

I some where seen that using -O3 will make compilers never bother about pointer types and considers everything as only bytes of memory but I couldn't find any improved performance even with -O3 flag.

Note: I am only concerned about performance not readability. I know that using union when we have limited number of types to deal with is a good approach for improving readability.

Comment: What happens if you reverse the tests or free the memory used for the first one before starting the second?

Comment: At the least, I'd want to see the result of wrapping `for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++) { … }` around the timing code in `main()` — or move the timing code into a function that is called multiple times from `main()`.  One run simply isn't informative, IMO; I'd want to see the result of 10 or more iterations of the tests (in a single process — not running the program 10 times from the command line).  I've not scrutinized your code to see whether there's anything untoward in how the void pointer code operates compared to the union alteranative

Comment: Allocating a Gb of pointers vs. a Gb of int's... Isn't this "apples vs oranges"? How big to you think allocated pages are?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Reversing tests seem to reverse the results as well. Is it due to caching? or any other specific reason.

Comment: How much physical memory does the computer you're running this on have? Enough to keep ~25 gigabytes of data in memory all at once? My guess is it doesn't so the second test forces memory to be swapped to disk and slows everything down.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yeah, after reducing memory allocations. I am finding similar speeds. I think I can close the question now.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Tried your suggestion and found alternating results but it was due to over allocation of memory after downing it. I am seeing similar results.

Comment: You cannot really argue on performance (at this level) without a specific compiler, specific build options, and specific target. All these information is missing. The rule of thumb is to run well designed performance tests for _your_ environment.

Comment: Anyway, is your current solution so near the limits that you need to think about such micro-optimizations? Use a 10% faster system, and all your worries are futile. Do not optimize premature, especially if it leads to bad source code like here using void pointers.

Comment: Performance questions need to mention how you benchmark, which compiler you use, the exact compiler options used and the target system. Without _all_ of this information, it is senseless to discuss performance.

Comment: `memcpy(fp->intElems[i], &i, sizeof(int));` is certainly a problem when the sizes of `size_t`, `vpid *` and `int` differ.

Answer (score 1):

Your code generates on [godbolt with gcc13.2 and -O3](https://godbolt.org/z/W7hjeeY71) the following assembly:

```
printUnionInt:
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rdi+16]
        test    rdx, rdx
        je      .L1
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
        lea     rcx, [rax+rdx*8]
.L3:
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rax]
        add     rax, 8
        add     DWORD PTR [rdx], 1
        cmp     rcx, rax
        jne     .L3
.L1:
        ret
printVoidPointerInt:
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rdi+16]
        test    rdx, rdx
        je      .L9
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
        lea     rcx, [rax+rdx*8]
.L11:
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rax]
        add     rax, 8
        add     DWORD PTR [rdx], 1
        cmp     rcx, rax
        jne     .L11
.L9:
        ret
```

I took a ruler and measured each function length, and it is exactly the same. There is no difference.

You may be interested in https://quick-bench.com/ .

> My question is does void pointer take more time than union since we need to type cast it again and again.

In assembly there are no types, a register is a register. Casting a pointer is something in C world, in assembly it is a no-op, nothing happens.

Comment: Then why is void pointer approach taking more time?

Comment: @widesense probably because your testing method is at fault.

Comment: Dry wit is almost as good as sarcasm... A ruler? `:)`

Comment: The issue was with over allocation of memory then I have in my machine due to switch lot of page swap is happening.